# Transition matrix for vector space of polynomials realized by evaluating at x_i

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, change-of-basis

I know how to perform a regular change of basis from one basis of the polynomial vector space to another bit what I am struggling with is that this involves evaluating the polynomials first. The problem is stated as:

Let two bases $\{p_0(x), \ldots , p_n(x)\}$ and $\{q_0(x), \ldots , q_n(x)\}$ of the space $\mathcal{P}_n$ of polynomials of degree $n$ be given. Let distinct interpolation points $x_i\,, i = 0, \ldots , n$ , be given.

Define the matrices $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ by

$$ \mathbf{G}_{ij} = p_j(x_i), \qquad \mathbf{H}_{ij} = q_j(x_i) $$

Show that the matrix $\mathbf{G}^{-1}\mathbf{H}$ realizes a change of basis. i.e.

$$ c = \mathbf{G}^{-1}\mathbf{H}d \implies \sum_i c_i p_i = \sum_i d_i q_i $$

What strikes me is that the fact that the polynomials were evaluated at $x_i$ complete disappears in the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

**Proof:** We know that for a set of interpolation points $x_i\,, i = 0, \ldots , n$ the Lagrange polynomials $l_i(x)\,, i = 0, \ldots , n$ are a basis ( let's call it $L_{x_i}$ ) of $\mathcal{P}_n$ . This means that every polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_n$ can be represented as a linear combination of $l_i(x)\,, i = 0, \ldots , n$ . By the definition for Lagrange Interpolation these linear combination look like (for an arbitrary polynomial $p \in \mathcal{P}_n$ ):

$$ p = \sum_{i=0}^n p(x_i)l_i(x_i) $$

This means that the matrices $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are just the representations of $\{p_0(x), \ldots , p_n(x)\}$ and $\{q_0(x), \ldots , q_n(x)\}$ with regards to the basis $L_{x_i}$ . This also means that they are the transition matrices to $$ .

$$ \mathbf{G}_{ij} = \mathbf{C}_{L_{x_i} \leftarrow P}, \qquad \mathbf{H}_{ij} = \mathbf{C}_{L_{x_i} \leftarrow Q} $$

Further we know that for a given change of basis matrix $\mathbf{C}_{A \leftarrow B}$ the determinant is non-zero and the inverse of that matrix

$$\mathbf{C}_{A \leftarrow B}^{-1} = \mathbf{C}_{B \leftarrow A}$$

realizes the opposite transition. And lastly we know that

$$\mathbf{C}_{C \leftarrow A} = \mathbf{C}_{C \leftarrow B} \mathbf{C}_{B \leftarrow A}$$

This means that:

$$ \mathbf{G}_{ij} = \mathbf{C}_{L_{x_i} \leftarrow P} \implies \mathbf{G}_{ij}^{-1} = \mathbf{C}_{P \leftarrow L_{x_i}}  $$

And since $\mathbf{H}_{ij} = \mathbf{C}_{L_{x_i} \leftarrow Q}$:

$$ \mathbf{C}_{P \leftarrow Q} = \mathbf{C}_{P \leftarrow L_{x_i}} \mathbf{C}_{L_{x_i} \leftarrow Q} = \mathbf{G}_{ij}^{-1} \mathbf{H}_{ij}$$